# angular repeating page element with select:option variant

Tags: angularjs

So I have a simple voltage option that comes from angular, but I want to specify the voltage to each scope element.

```
 $scope.pages = [
      {'image':'/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x/50d17836c695199ec6d8f9e4624bdf5c/p/h/photo_8_1.jpg'},{'image':'/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x/50d17836c695199ec6d8f9e4624bdf5c/p/h/photo_8_2.jpg'}
      ]; 

       <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="content in pages">
        <p>Voltage <select ng-if="">
            <option>208</option>
            <option>230</option>
            <option>460</option>
        </select></p>
        </div>
```

is there a way to have it have the first record hide option 208 and the second show all the options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-show or ng-hide on each option that you want to control visibility of.  From there, apply your rules such as hide the first option on the first record.  In your case, use `ng-hide="$first"` for the first option.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="content in pages">
   <p>Voltage <select>
            <option ng-hide="$first">208</option>
            <option>230</option>
            <option>460</option>
   </select></p>
</div>
```